# Open a Settings Window

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, scenebuilder

I would like to create a Settings Window, when I klick on a MenuItem.
On the settings screen I want to change the Ip Adress of an server.

The main screen is created with the Scenebuilder but I would like to create the settings window manual. Currently I have no idea where to start.

Shall i create a class wich extends Application and open it when I click the Menu Item or can I code it directly in the controller class of the main screen ?

Thank you for your help

Comment: *"Shall i create a class wich extends Application"* No! *"or can I code it directly in the controller class of the main screen?"* You could, but I wouldn't recommend that either, since the Settings part seems to be sufficiently different from the "main" part to move the code to it's own class, which contains methods to create the scene ect.

Comment: Ok, thank you verry much I will try it.